# How to setup tables in Rmarkdown using {tabular}

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am just learning how to use Rmarkdown. I know this is a fairly simple solution but I can't seem to resolve it. I first made my table using | and -- as line separators, I then searched online and found some info on using latex language to center and configure tables using {tabular}. I keep getting a error for an alignment tab changed to /cr. I searched this error and all I get is that I have non designated the proper columns that I have specified. Here is my code. Not sure where I'm going wrong:

```
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{TITLE OF TABLE}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
\hline 
  Volts (V) & Starting Concentration (mg N/L) & $NH_4-N$ removal (%) & $NH_4-N$ after 18 hrs (%) \\ \hline
0 & 50 & 92.3 & 86.4 \\ 
0 & 25 & 90.6 & 86.0 \\
0 & 5 & 92.8 & 82.3 \\
1.8 & 50 & 78.8 & NA \\
1.8 & 25 & 74.7 & 103.1* \\
1.8 & 5 & 62.0 & 74.9 \\
2.4 & 50 & 70.0 & 94.4 \\
2.4 & 25 & 63.1 & 100.6 \\
2.4 & 5 & 65.8 & 57.5 \\
3.6 & 50 & 78.2 & 79.4 \\
3.6 & 25 & 63.8 & 98.7 \\
3.6 & 5 & 42.6 & 40.8* \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I get errors like:
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule @height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.233 \hline

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be fixed quite quickly, you need to escape the `%` character that is present twice:

```
  Volts (V) & Starting Concentration (mg N/L) & $NH_4-N$ removal (%) & $NH_4-N$ after 18 hrs (%) \\ \hline
```

should be changed to

```
  Volts (V) & Starting Concentration (mg N/L) & $NH_4-N$ removal (\%) & $NH_4-N$ after 18 hrs (\%) \\ \hline
```

This is because the `%` character is the symbol for comments in LaTeX.